# Apache Spark/scala: Handle yarn kill to perform actions before quitting (clean up resources, save the state)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, handler, kill, resource-cleanup

I have multiple unrelated jobs running on Spark/Hadoop grid executors started by a single spark-submit from the driver node. When I need to stop the jobs, I'd like to save their IDs before the driver node program quits (or, more generally: to do something like save the state and/or clean up resources, it doesn't matter).

Is there a way to handle a yarn termination event to perform such operations as you would do it by analogy with POSIX signals by handling SIGTERM signal (& friends) to perform some *last chance* clean up.

I haven't found a way to handle yarn kill. Is there a way? Is there an alternative to yarn kill that would satisfy that need?

Thanks. Regards.

Comment: I am not aware of functions like that. I would just save on HDFS/HBase/Kudu the state at regular time intervals, then read the latest state on the job startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Spark listener with onApplicationEnd to handle the yarn kill event:

```
sparkContext.addSparkListener(new SparkListener {
    override def onApplicationEnd(applicationEnd: SparkListenerApplicationEnd): Unit = {
    }
}
```

Apache Ignite (in the version I use) does exactly that for that purpose.